# Rails + Bootstrap Theme: Bootstrap overrides my CSS / Google Fonts

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, themes

I am currently trying to integrate a Bootstrap theme into my rails project. I have installed the Bootstrap-Sass Gem & am trying to use Google Fonts using their provided link tags in the header. Currently it seems as though Bootstrap is overriding the Google Fonts (& possibly other CSS) and I'm not sure how to fix this.  I realize that there have been several similar questions asked about this, but so far the solutions I've tried havn't seemed to work.

I'm sure that Bootstrap is installed correctly because other bootstrap styling works.

I've tried moving things around in my `application.css` file but no luck.

I've tried adding an `@import` link into my CSS file instead of using a link in the head tag.

I know that I can add `!important` to the css attributes (which works but I'd rather not go that route...unless this is one of those exceptions that calls for it??).

My `application.rb` has `config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")`.

I've used Google Fonts many times with no problems.  I just can't figure out what I'm missing.  Did I just not organize my CSS manifest file correctly?  I've read that the order you require your assets in the manifest matters, but I'm not clear in every situation when it does.  In my case, `template.css` is the main css file I'm trying to get to work.  Should that be placed below the bootstrap `@imports` and if so, how (when I attempted this strange things happened)?

Application.css.scss

```
/*
 *= require bootstrap.min
 *= require themify-icons
 *= require magnific-popup
 *= require vertical.min
 *= require template
 *= require jquery-ui
 *= require font-awesome
*/

@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

My application.html.erb file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Portfolio</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <!-- Favicons-->
    <%= favicon_link_tag 'favicon.png' %>
    <%= favicon_link_tag 'apple-touch-icon.png' %>
    <%= favicon_link_tag 'apple-touch-icon-72x72.png' %>
    <%= favicon_link_tag 'apple-touch-icon-114x114.png' %>
    <!-- Web Fonts-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Suranna" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>

  <body>

    <%= yield %>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found an answer, and as I suspected the problem was with how I had my files ordered in `application.css` (I must not have tried this particular order that got it working). I changed my manifest to:

```
/*
 *= require bootstrap.min
 *= require themify-icons
 *= require magnific-popup
 *= require vertical.min
 *= require jquery-ui
 *= require font-awesome
*/

@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "template"
```

It was necessary to move my `template.css.scss` file below the bootstrap imports in order for things to load correctly.  I have a feeling that I will need to do some more reorganizing there with some of the other requirements, but at least this solved the google font issue & taught me something about how the asset pipeline works in Rails.

Comment: Good for you. For future reference, note that it's worth looking into layouts/application.html.erb as the HEAD tag makes reference to stylesheet_link_tag. You can put your own CSS (eg. from CDNs) before or after that, as required.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should put the code below in your application.css

```
     *= require_tree .
     *= require_self
```

like this

```
    /*
     *= require bootstrap.min
     *= require themify-icons
     *= require magnific-popup
     *= require vertical.min
     *= require template
     *= require jquery-ui
     *= require font-awesome
     *= require_tree .
     *= require_self
    */
```

Comment: Unfortunately no, that did not solve the problem. I purposefully removed those lines earlier in the project.  Thanks for trying to help though!  See my solution above.  This is the first time using a template so things were a little different than usual with how i needed to set up my assets.